# Use Python Requests on ChartMogul API

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I try to use the API of ChartMogul with Python. And since they don't have a client library for it, I need to do it myself. This is the API example:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.chartmogul.com/v1/import/customers" \
     -u YOUR_ACCOUNT_TOKEN:YOUR_SECRET_KEY \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{
          "data_source_uuid": "ds_fef05d54-47b4-431b-aed2-eb6b9e545430",
          "external_id": "cus_0001",
          "name": "Adam Smith",
          "email": "adam@smith.com",
          "country": "US",
          "city": "New York"
         }'
```

This is what I do:

```
import requests

url     = "https://api.chartmogul.com/v1/import/customers"
data_source_uuid = "the uuid I get from my api data source"
token = 'my token'
key= 'my key'
payload = {
          "data_source_uuid": data_source_uuid,
          "external_id": "cus_0001",
          "name": "Adam Smith",
          "email": "adam@smith.com",
          "country": "US",
          "city": "New York"
         }

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
res = requests.post(url,
    auth=(token, key),
    data=payload,
    headers=headers)
```

But I have a response 400 (bad request). What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
data=json.dumps(payload),
```

instead of

```
data=payload,
```

Comment: Oh my... Cannot believe that it was so simple! Sometimes it is just like this. Thank you. When the time limit passes, I will choose your answer as best.